# Office365 /Azure Login populate users Email

Tags: php, azure, ms-office, office365-apps

I am writing an app that connects to office 365 to pull the users newest X emails and show as a preview on their dashboard.

What I have is:

- user loads the page.
- logs them in via adfs sso
- redirects back to the dashboard
- redirects to office 365 login ( via my oAuth script  - https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize, resource: https://outlook.office365.com/, state: MD5 ID, login_hint = urlencoded email, WHR = adfs.domain.com ( not right ).
- the email address is pre-populated, they have to TAB out of the email field, and are redirected back to their adfs server before entering a password.
- adfs confirms login and redirects to their dashboard - shows email.

What I understand from reading the below resources, I can pass the WHR param, that will bypass the azure login.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2424.windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-utilize-the-ws-federation-whr-parameter-to-bypass-home-realm-discovery-hrd.aspx

Here is an example:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?
resource' => https://outlook.office365.com/
login_hint => urlencode(email)
WHR => https://adfs.domain.com/
state => uuid
```

[UPDATED workflow]
Thanks.

Comment: I have tried sending the param 'username' => 'email@domain.com' as a param with the request, this did not work.

Comment: Adding 'login_hint' => urlencode('email@domian.com') to my params populates the field, but you still have to tab in, then out of the field to get the page to redirect.

Comment: From Research, There is a WHR param that I can pass with the IDP URL.But adding the full path the the ADFS server doesn't do anything, Eg: 'whr' => 'https://adfs.domain.com/'

Comment: Reference links 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2424.windows-identity-foundation-wif-how-to-utilize-the-ws-federation-whr-parameter-to-bypass-home-realm-discovery-hrd.aspx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.